# How to Connect Arduino to pubnub cloud using esp8266?

Tags: arduino, pubnub, iot, esp8266

I am trying to interface arduino to the pubnub cloud by using esp8266, please suggest me the best solution to push data from arduino kit to cloud and also to get the same data to devices from cloud.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is [a short tutorial](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-07-14-basic-iot-publishsubscribe-messaging-for-esp8266/) on how to use PubNub with the ESP8266

Note that this uses custom firmware, not standard Arduino. According to [this link](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/esp8266-thing-hookup-guide/installing-the-esp8266-arduino-addon) you can now use regular Arduino directly, meaning you should be able to use PubNub's [standard Arduino api](https://github.com/pubnub/arduino).

Comment: Hey, I wrote that tutorial! I always prefer custom firmware - especially since the ESP8266 has I/O of its own with no need of a controller for most projects I have seen it used with.